# Pandas keep latest row and aggregate value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe for Projects. If a project fails a test then that test is repeated at a later data and passed value updated.
df_Project =

```
Date    Project_ID  TestA   TestB   TestC   TestD
27072020    Project1    Pass    Pass    Pass    Fail
30072020    Project1    None    None    None    Pass
```

I want to create another dataframe which keeps the last date only and aggregates the test results as Pass if any date passed.
df_Summary =

```
Date    Project_ID  TestA   TestB   TestC   TestD
30072020    Project1    Pass    Pass    Pass    Pass
```

How can i do it in pandas?

Comment: You better convert `Date` into datetime, so you can use `max` to get the last dates. Otherwise, `30072020 > 010802020` ....

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

You can do `groupby` with `max`

```
out=df.groupby('Project_ID').max().reset_index()
Out[115]: 
  Project_ID      Date TestA TestB TestC TestD
0   Project1  30072020  Pass  Pass  Pass  Pass
```

The reason why this work

```
'Pass'>'Fail'
Out[116]: True
```

Comment: @YOBEN_S I tried your solution but it doesn't work, I even converted the date to datetime:
>>> df.groupby('ProjID').max().reset_index()
  ProjID       Date TestA TestB TestC TestD
0  Proj1 2020-07-27  Pass  Pass  Pass  Fail
1  Proj2 2020-07-30  None  None  None  Pass